# In Solidity is it possible to create a token, $TOKEN, where sending $TOKEN from one wallet to another is restricted?

Tags: solidity, tokens

I want to implement this feature in a token for fun. Is there a way to make it so that the only way a wallet can receive tokens is by buying them on a dex, or getting them using a smart contract; not by getting sent tokens from another wallet?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to control sender and recipient by overriding transfer and transferFrom and deny the operation by reverting.

A token that prevents user from transferring them would be pretty useless or a scam.